# Problems in updating a SQL Server 2008 in C#. NET in runtime mode

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have faced a problem to update a row in SQL Serve 2008 via C#. NET application.

During runtime, the application tries to update the database but with no success. However, there is no exception, error, NOTHING. Checking the SQL Profile, the update command was sent, but not committed.

If I run the application debugging it step-by-step (via 'F11') the row is updated successfully (!?!?!?!?!)

I have copied the SQL update command and ran it on SQL Management Studio and also worked fine.

General Information:
- The only problem is in runtime mode.
- The user used is 'sa' with all granted permission
- I have ran the SAME METHODS for other tables (the only thing that changes is the table name) and it works fine.

The method responsible for it is:

```
    public void Save(FormaResult obj)
    {
        try
        {
            bool insert = GetById(obj.SLABID) == null;

            IList<string> colResult = GetColumns(TABLE);
            List<string> colList = colResult.Where(TableColumns.Contains).ToList();

            if (insert)
            {
                string col = string.Join(",", colList.Select(i => i).ToArray());
                string colParam = string.Join(", ", colList.Select(i => "@" + i).ToArray());
                QueryString = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE + " (" + col + ") VALUES(" + colParam + ");";
            }
            else
            {
                string colSet = string.Join(", ", colList.Select(i => i + " = @" + i).ToArray());
                QueryString = "UPDATE " + TABLE + " SET " + colSet + " WHERE SLABID = @Id1;";
            }

            DbCommand = Conn.CreateCommand();
            DbCommand.Connection = Conn;
            DbCommand.CommandText = QueryString;

            ListDbParameters = new List<DbParameter>
            {
                this.CriarParametro<DateTime>("GT_TIME", obj.GT_TIME),
                this.CriarParametro<long?>("SLABID", obj.SLABID),                    
                this.CriarParametro<short?>("STATUS", obj.STATUS)
            };

            if (!insert)
            {
                ListDbParameters.Add(this.CriarParametro<long>("Id1", obj.SLABID));
            }

            foreach (DbParameter param in ListDbParameters)
            {
                DbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
            }

            Conn.Open();
            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TrkCGManagedModuleService.Logger.Error(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I have also used this method:

```
    public void OkEvt()
    {
        try
        {
            this.QueryString = "UPDATE " + TABLE + " SET STATUS = 1 " +
                               "FROM (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE STATUS=0 ORDER BY GT_TIME ASC) I " +
                               "WHERE " + TABLE + ".SLABID = I.SLABID AND " + TABLE + ".STATUS=0 AND " + TABLE + ".GT_TIME = I.GT_TIME;";

            this.DbCommand = this.Conn.CreateCommand();
            this.DbCommand.Connection = this.Conn;
            this.DbCommand.CommandText = this.QueryString;

            this.Conn.Open();
            this.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TrkCGManagedModuleService.Logger.Error(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Both methods have the same aim, update the column 'STATUS' to '1'.

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! :)

Comment: open sql server profiler and look what query you getting there

Comment: What is the table name? Try putting the table name between [ and ] like UPDATE [mytable] SET .......

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV the query in Sql profiler is OK, if I copy it and run it, works fine.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I have already done it and nothing changed.

Comment: can you comment the sql profiler query here ?

Comment: if the query is detected in profiler and if you copy and paste it to ssms then if it is working fine then there is no problem

Comment: Is there any multithreading happening? Could it be that this.QueryString or this.DbCommand get overwritten by some other thread? Why don't you create/dispose the command/connection for each execute?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV the command in sql profiler is: exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE tb_pdo_result_temperatura SET GT_TIME = #GT_TIME, SLABID = #SLABID, STATUS = #STATUS WHERE SLABID = #Id1; ',N'#GT_TIME datetime, #SLABID bigint, #STATUS smallint, #Id1 bigint', #GT_TIME='2015-10-17 12:28:08', #I_SLABID=38062060, #STATUS=1, #Id1=38062060. Note that a replace '@' for '#' because stackoverflow does not allow put more than one '@' as user...

Comment: yes you have to check whether any other query is overwrite your details

Comment: @jtmnt it is single thread, it is just executed by one in a sync way. I can use 'dispose' for each execute as improvement. Thanks.

Comment: if you really must use same DbCommand many times (why?), you may want to try clearing existing CommandParameters before adding new ones. (Edit: Actually now I see Command is re-created anyway, so that shouldn't be it)

Comment: What you need to do is then to compare the sql statements executed during debugging (success) and during runtime (failure). Do those two differ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the same thing as Soner Gonul about the SQL injection.  I understand what your trying to do, but from my experience your leaving open a security door that is easily closed.  Just requires a bit more time writing your CRUD statements for each table.

Here is a code sample that I use for my update queries you might find useful.  If you are going to use this method, remember to create a user that has deny reader and deny writer.  Then run a command to grant them execute permissions on all stored procedures.

**this.o_ConnectionString** is a private variable set inside my class constructor since i put my data layer in a separate project than my web applications.

```
public int UpdateThisTable(int TableUID, string SomeField)
{

        string StoredProcedure = "usp_SomeStoredProcedure";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(enteryourconnectionstring);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedure, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableUID", TableUID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeField", SomeField);

        conn.Open();
        int rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        return rowsaffected;
}
```

Comment: what is the use of DataSet  here ?

Comment: lol, oops, leftovers from one of my select command dataset fills.  Please disregard that line. :)